# How to fix the position of an element regardless of the items around?

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

I created a search form with some `nav-tabs` and a button to let the user change the language.
My problem is that whenever I change the language the position of the button changes as well, for the lengths of the strings in the `nav-items` differ (e.g. if I translate "City" in Spanish, the string becomes "Ciudad" and the button moves to the right for the length of the string is greater).

In other terms, when the strings are longer the boxes of the `nav-tabs` are wider as well, therefore the button is moved to the right.

I want to fix its position to the right of the `nav-items`, independently of which is the length of the strings inside.

The button is a [Bootstrap dropdown button](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/) and lives inside the same `<div>` where I put the `nav-items`. I also set its position to `relative` for I want to fix it in relation to the width of the screen ("`translate`" is the `ID` of the button):

```css
#translate {
  background-color: #d63040;
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="form-inline nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a lang="en" class="nav-link active" id="citta-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#citta" role="tab" aria-controls="citta" aria-selected="true">CITY</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a lang="en" class="nav-link" id="regione-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#region" role="tab" aria-controls="region" aria-selected="false">REGION</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a lang="en" class="nav-link" id="about-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#about" role="tab" aria-controls="about" aria-selected="false">ABOUT</a>
  </li>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button id="translate" type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <i class="fas fa-language"></i>
                        </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a id="itButton" class="dropdown-item" href="#lang-en" onclick="window.lang.change('it');return false;">It</a>
      <a id="frButton" class="dropdown-item" href="#lang-en" onclick="window.lang.change('fr');return false;">Fr</a>
      <a id="enButton" class="dropdown-item" href="#lang-en" onclick="window.lang.change('en');return false;">En</a>
      <a id="esButton" class="dropdown-item" href="#lang-en" onclick="window.lang.change('es');return false;">Es</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Ideally, I would like to fix the position more to the right of the nav-items, as in the following image:

[image: ideal position]

However, if I set a greater value (for instance, 300px) the button disappears when I resize the screen:

[image: the button disappears]

How may I fix the position of such a button regardless of the elements around? And how may I do that by keeping its position "relative" to the size of the window of the browser?

Comment: Have you tried adding `margin-left:100px`
This will make your button move right of 100 pixels

Comment: Why do you wan't to keep the possition as ```relative```. Can't you just set it as ```absolute``` and set up a ```right``` and ```top``` value?

Comment: `float` the button group right? Or position the button group `absolute`, position the `ul` relative and set the button group to the far right with `right: 0`.

Comment: if you want it to be independent from other elements then you'll have to use position absolute

Comment: @Synapsis yes I tried, it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Kaddath yes my mistake, I fixed it

Comment: @Pbras Why do you think is better? I did it but the button is moved to the right when the length of the strings is greater

Comment: @franz1 That way the button will keep in the same possition even if you change the language and won't be relative to any other element like you wanted. But since you want to use relative "keeping its position "relative" don't know if it will work for you.

Comment: @franz1 You have to remove the position:relative and add margin-left

Answer (score 2):

this might be a way to solve our problem

```css
.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar">
  <ul class="form-inline nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a lang="en" class="nav-link active" id="citta-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#citta" role="tab" aria-controls="citta" aria-selected="true">CITY</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a lang="en" class="nav-link" id="regione-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#region" role="tab" aria-controls="region" aria-selected="false">REGION</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a lang="en" class="nav-link" id="about-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#about" role="tab" aria-controls="about" aria-selected="false">ABOUT</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button id="translate" type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="fas fa-language"></i>
                    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a id="itButton" class="dropdown-item" href="#lang-en" onclick="window.lang.change('it');return false;">It</a>
      <a id="frButton" class="dropdown-item" href="#lang-en" onclick="window.lang.change('fr');return false;">Fr</a>
      <a id="enButton" class="dropdown-item" href="#lang-en" onclick="window.lang.change('en');return false;">En</a>
      <a id="esButton" class="dropdown-item" href="#lang-en" onclick="window.lang.change('es');return false;">Es</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Valid and semantic html +1. This is also a specifically good use-case for flexbox.

Comment: tnx @UncaughtTypeError

Answer (score 1):

```
position: static;
white-space: normal;
float: right;
```

Hopefully, this will do the trick for you.

Comment: Where do you add that?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by doing the following:

1) In the HTML file, I create a new `<div>` for the `<h1>` element and moved the `<button>` inside it:

```
<div class="form-inline">

            <!-- h1 element -->
            <a href="" class="link-home" id="buttonTitle"><h1 id="TitleH1" class="display-4"> Discover the Amazing
                Route </h1></a>

            <!-- Button -->                
            <div class="btn-group float-right">
                <button id="translate" type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"
                        aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="fas fa-language"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a id="itButton" class="dropdown-item" href="#lang-en"
                       onclick="window.lang.change('it');return false;">It</a>
                    <a id="frButton" class="dropdown-item" href="#lang-en"
                       onclick="window.lang.change('fr');return false;">Fr</a>
                    <a id="enButton" class="dropdown-item" href="#lang-en"
                       onclick="window.lang.change('en');return false;">En</a>
                    <a id="esButton" class="dropdown-item" href="#lang-en"
                       onclick="window.lang.change('es');return false;">Es</a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

2) I assigned a `margin-right` to the `<h1>` element to place distance between the title and the button: by doing so, I can move the button horizontally (the wider is the margin of the `<h1>`, the more distant is the button):

```
h1 {        
    margin-right: 585px;
}
```

3) I assigned the Bootstrap class `float-right` to the button to float it to the right (see [Boostrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/float/)):

```
<div class="btn-group float-right">
  <!-- ... --> 
</div>
```

By doing so, I could place the button where I wanted; at the same time it doesn't disappear when the window of the browser is resized and made the smallest as possible.